# Elastic Beanstalk change environment variables wipes out WSGIPassAuthorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a custom file in .ebextensions:

```
container_commands:
    02_wsgipass:
        command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

When I change the environment variables through the Elastic Beanstalk UI, it wipes out the WSGIPassAuthorization and I need to re-deploy the code.

Any way to correct that? Re-deploying the code is really not practical and removes the advantage of environment variables.